# How To Spanning multi-valued relationships?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Im Try to Catch any data from database with table name is '**UserUsulan**'.
I have two field, '**Ketua**' and '**Anggota**'.
In **Ketua** Field is ForeignKey from User, and **Anggota** is ManyToMany Field with relationship from User.

I want to render the data.
if in **Ketua** Field equal current.user render the data.
and also if current.user in **Anggota** field i want it render too.

So,
If the current.user is not able in **Ketua** Field, but able in **Anggota** Field. Render the Data
If the current.user is not able in **Anggota** Field, buat able in **Ketua** Field. Render the Data Too.

How To Solve this problem.
Im read with this documentation [Spanning multi-valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) . But the Queryset is empty[].

**models.py**

```
    tahun                       = models.IntegerField(_('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
judul_penelitian            = models.TextField(blank=True)
jenis_penelitian            = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, default="", choices=JENIS_PENELITIAN_CHOICE)
tmt_awal                    = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
tmt_akhir                   = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
bidang_penelitian           = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default="", choices=BIDANG_PENELITIAN_CHOICE)
tujuan_sosial_ekonomi       = models.TextField(blank=True)
sumber_dana                 = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="", choices=SUMBER_DANA_CHOICE)
skema_penelitian            = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, default="", choices=SKEMA_PENELITIAN_CHOICE)
jumlah_dana_usulan          = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='IDR')
target_luaran               = models.CharField(max_length=23, blank=True, default="", choices=TARGET_LUARAN_CHOICE)
ketua                       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='ketua_penelitian', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
anggota                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='anggota_penelitian')
upload_file                 = models.FileField(upload_to='Penelitian/', null=True, blank=True)
status_usulan               = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, choices=STATUS_USULAN_CHOICE, default='MENUNGGU')
jumlah_dana_disetujui       = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='IDR', null=True, blank=True)
keterangan_operator         = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
com_reviewer_1              = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
com_reviewer_2              = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset    = super(UserUsulanPenelitianCreateAndListView, self).get_queryset()
    queryset    = queryset.filter(ketua=self.request.user,).filter(anggota=self.request.user,)
    print(queryset)
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found The Answer, Using Q for the queryset

Import Q

```
from django.db.models import Q
```

Using Q in Queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset    = super(UserUsulanPenelitianCreateAndListView, self).get_queryset()
    queryset    = queryset.filter(Q(ketua=self.request.user)|Q(anggota=self.request.user)).distinct()
    print(queryset)
    return queryset
```